# Why do I not have access to fields that are client side modified in my code behind?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am trying to do a fetch in JavaScript. I have no issues and can get the value I need.  I need to pass this value to C# code behind. I have put the value in a hidden field, a div to get the innerHTML and a textbox.value. I don't know what is happening but I cannot seem to access this data from C#. I have an asp:button that executes client side script and then the code behind. Whenever the client side script returns true, the page refreshes.  I have tried returning false and the correct values remain on the page but they are not available in the code behind, which *is* executing (which I find strange since I returned false from the client side). I am including my various attempts so you can see all.

HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="secretTextBox" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="secretHiddenField" />
<div id="testdiv" runat="server">This is a test.</div>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRunMOReport" class="button-dbg" Text="Run MO Report" OnClick="btnMO_Report_Click" OnClientClick="return validateCheckBoxesMO()" />
```

JavaScript:

```
// So this makes sure the page is valid and if so executes the fetch
function validateCheckBoxesMO() {
const result = validateMO();
if (result && document.getElementById("rbMOMap").checked) {
    fetch(
        "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/generateToken?f=json&username=xxx&password=xxx&client=requestip"
    )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            token = data.token;
            document.getElementById("secretTextBox").value = token;
            document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = token;
        })
        // Garbage I know but I just wanted to force a false return but wait on the promise
        .then(finish => { return false });
} else {
    return result; // So this can return true but only if they are not getting the map.
    }
}
```

Code Behind (The Pertinent Part):
Mind you, at this point the textbox and the div both show the token I am looking for.

This is where I attempt to extract from the DIV:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
testdiv.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)));
string s = sb.ToString().Remove(sb.ToString().Length - 6, 6);
s = s.Remove(0, 18);
```

s is equal to "This is a test.", which was what it was at page load but not what it currently shows on the page.

At this point, while looking at the debugger, secretTextBox.Text = "", secretHiddenField.Value = "".

I have tried juggling this for days and attempting different ways of passing this value.  I cannot seem to do it. MVC is not really an option unless I want to rewrite the entire app. I feel I'm missing something very basic and I can't figure it out. Any assistance is appreciated.

It seems I might need to do the fetch from the code behind but I'm not that sophisticated at the C#.  If that appears to be an option, I would be fine with that.

Comment: If you follow through your javascript with the debugger you will see that document.getElementById("secretTextBox") does not find the element. Use the name property to identify them instead because the ASP.NET server changes the IDs on you.

Comment: I am baffled by your code that renders the DIV to a StringBuilder. If the value is stored in a hidden field, read it from the hidden field. If it's not stored in a hidden field (or other HTML input element), it is not available to the code behind because it was not sent over the wire.

Comment: Dave, the page renders the token in the textbox.  This indicates to me that the textbox has been altered yet it does not exist in the code behind.

Comment: John, I was attempting to read the DIV into the code behind.  The stripping of characters is just to get the <div></div> off the string. It reads the value that was in the div at page load but does not read the token that is clearly displayed in the div.

Comment: I guess I was tired yesterday.  I also tried secretHiddenField.value = token; after the two document statements yet in the code behind, secretHiddenField.value = "";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I made it work. I created an HTML button that ran my JavaScript. I prevented the default behavior so it wouldn't do a post back. Then, when the server button was pressed, the fields were there. It's ugly but it works.  If I prevented the default behavior on the client click, I wouldn't get the post back I needed. I still think this can be done in one button but I was not able to make it work that way.